# Unexpected wrapper element when using CXF generated client

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, cxf

I've generated a client for a webservice using CXF's wsdl2java.

THe client connects OK, but throws an expection complaining that the response found doesn't match the expected response.

```
May 22, 2013 3:44:46 PM org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromWSDL
INFO: Creating Service {http://www.service-now.com/cmdb_ci_comm}ServiceNow_cmdb_ci_comm from WSDL: file:/C:/Dev/Workspaces/Eclipse/clim20130508/ServiceNowCXFClient/bin/service-now.wsdl
Invoking getRecords...
May 22, 2013 3:44:51 PM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://www.service-now.com/foo}ServiceNow_foo#{http://www.service-now.com/foo}getRecords has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unexpected wrapper element getRecordsResponse found.   Expected {http://www.service-now.com/foo}getRecordsResponse.
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:100)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:800)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1592)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1490)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1309)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:622)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:366)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:319)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:133)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29.getRecords(Unknown Source)
at com.service_now.cmdb_ci_comm.ServiceNowSoap_ServiceNowSoap_Client.main(ServiceNowSoap_ServiceNowSoap_Client.java:178)
```

Clearly, the received response differs from the expected response in that the latter includes a namespace.

```
getRecordsResponse found.   Expected {http://www.service-now.com/foo}getRecordsResponse
```

My service client opens as follows...

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "ServiceNow_foo", 
              wsdlLocation = "service-now.wsdl",
              targetNamespace = "http://www.service-now.com/foo") 
public class ServiceNowFoo extends Service {

    public final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;

    public final static QName SERVICE = new QName("http://www.service-now.com/foo", "ServiceNow_foo");
    public final static QName ServiceNowSoap = new QName("http://www.service-now.com/foom", "ServiceNowSoap");
```

You can see the client code in the question [How does one configure CXF generated client for preemptive HTTP auth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698404/how-does-one-configure-cxf-generated-client-for-preemptive-http-auth)

Any ideas as to what the misconfiguration is?

Answer (score 0):

An explanation may be found here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-1460 though it is a long closed bug.

I am struggling with the same issue with CXF and ServiceNow when the WSDL that ServiceNow exposes has `elementFormDefault="unqualified"`. I noticed that the generated `package-info.java` does not have the the correct `@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema` annotation since it misses `elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED` I am using CXF 3.2.4 with Glassfish Java XML Binding 2.3.0

A workaround to make the client work is to set the `glide.wsdl.schema.UnqualifiedElementFormDefault` parameter in ServiceNow to `false` .