# How can I make jaxws parse response without checking Content-Type header

Tags: soap, jax-ws

I am calling a soap webservice via jax ws client code (generated from wsdl). 
But the service sends response with "Content-Type:text/html" where as the jax-ws implementation requires "text/xml" type.
The webservice folk won't change the response header.

Exception is :

> com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server
>   sent HTTP status code 200: OK     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.createResponsePacket(HttpTransportPipe.java:266)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_171]    at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:217)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_171]    at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:130)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_171]    at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:124)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_171]

Also tried with Saaj Implementation. It also mandates response Content-Type header to be text/xml.
Here is the exception with saaj :

> Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl:
>   Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a
>   SOAP response?    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(MessageImpl.java:655)
>   ~[?:1.8.0_171]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)

Is there a way to make jaxws ignore response header and continue parsing?

Comment: What type of application server are you running on and whats the version?  E.g. websphere, glassfish, JBoss or Tomcat?

Comment: spring boot with embedded tomcat. I can't parse response from a webservice I call in the code because it's returning wrong soap content type : test/html

Comment: Whats the tomcat version?

Comment: tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29

Comment: You should be able to use an CXF interceptor or JAX-WS handler though I know overly complicated for your needs but likely your only choice [how do i modify http headers for a jax-ws response in cxf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736709/how-do-i-modify-http-headers-for-a-jax-ws-response-in-cxf) if you go the JAX-WS route, I have more experience with it as currently using it in project!

Comment: Thanks @JGlass. Will try that option and get back

Comment: Thanks @JGlass. I checked CXF. Wrote as an answer what made it work. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't exactly find a solution with jax-ws but thanks to @JGlass found a pleasantly simple solution with apache cfx. Very flexible implementation of jax-ws. In love with it.
Here is the simple code that made it work :

```
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
    client.getInInterceptors().add(new AbstractPhaseInterceptor<org.apache.cxf.message.Message>(Phase.RECEIVE) {
        public void handleMessage(org.apache.cxf.message.Message message) {
            message.put(org.apache.cxf.message.Message.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/xml");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Awesome you got it working - glad I could help point you in the right direction!

Comment: @JGlass this looks like a very clean solution! I have taken the liberty to include this in my [write-up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71734557/3756780) on this subject, and created a fully working example client on my github: https://github.com/s-lindenau/SoapContentTypeDemo/tree/master/client-cxf

Comment: @slindenau, nice write up and good job contributing on GIT, I am sure it may help many with similar problems!!